# Turning a proportion of responses into binary response variable for logistic regression in R

Tags: r, regression, logistic-regression

So, I have had a question pop up that requires me to generate a response variable (the response needs to be binary with a simple yes or no) in a logistic regression model based off proportional data of a certain outcome and specific dummy variable inputs like gender that will give me the probability of `YES` occuring.

The data looks somewhat like this *(it's not the exact data, I just cobbled this together based off the layout of the original data)*:

| Yes | No | Total | dummy1(1,2) | dummy2(1,2) | dummy3(1,2,3) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 30 | 35 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 6 | 7 | 13 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 20 | 24 | 2 | 2 | 3 |
| 25 | 129 | 154 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 13 | 42 | 65 | 1 | 1 | 2 |

I'm wondering how I get a binary response variable from the given proportions? I understand the concepts of logistic regression - it's more the `R-code` that I don't understand because we have had no relevant examples of converting a proportion like this to a binary response in class...

Would something like the following code give me a desired equation to model the probability of `YES` occurring?:

```
dat.glmL <- glm(cbind(Yes, No) ~ factor(dummy1(1,2))+factor(dummy2(1,2))+factor(dummy3(1,2,3)), 
data = data, family = "binomial")
```

Would it be important to add the `weight` argument for the `glm()` function?

(I'm aware `glm()` is the function for the model, and I have plenty of examples for adequacy testing and significance through `ANOVA` in `R`, it's just this initial conversion...).

Thanks!

Comment: `cbind(Yes, No)` will work and model what you have in mind. I would convert the factor variables in `data` prior to calling `glm` although I think what you show will work also, and would advise not to call objects in the environment `data` or as any other R function names for that matter.

Comment: `dummy1(1,2)`, etc, are very bad names for variables, the R parser will probably see them as function calls. Since those names without the `(.)` stuff are unique, remove the parenthesis and there will be no problems.

Comment: I should add, that my table is an example, it's not the actual column or variable names in my work. It was just used as a mock data-set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#Preparing data:

df1 <- df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols= c(Yes, No),
    names_to = "response_name",
    values_to = "response_value"
  ) %>% 
  mutate(response_name = case_when(response_name == "Yes" ~ "1",
                                   response_name == "No" ~ "0"),
         response_name = as.numeric(response_name))

xtabs(response_value ~ ., df1)

fit <- glm(response_name ~ `dummy1(1,2)`, weights = response_value, data = df1, family = binomial)

summary(fit)
```

Output:

```
Call:
glm(formula = response_name ~ `dummy1(1,2)`, family = binomial, 
    data = df1, weights = response_value)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-6.7736  -3.6590   0.9414   4.0899   9.5249  

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)    -0.7461     0.5084  -1.468    0.142
`dummy1(1,2)`  -0.4453     0.3091  -1.441    0.150

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 272.12  on 9  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 270.07  on 8  degrees of freedom
AIC: 274.07

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5
```

data:

```
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Yes,  ~No, ~Total, ~`dummy1(1,2)`, ~`dummy2(1,2)`, ~`dummy3(1,2,3)`,
    5L,  30L,    35L,             1L,             2L,               3L,
    6L,   7L,    13L,             1L,             1L,               1L,
    4L,  20L,    24L,             2L,             2L,               3L,
   25L, 129L,   154L,             2L,             1L,               2L,
   13L,  42L,    65L,             1L,             1L,               2L
  )
```